# Avro to BigTable - Schema issue?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, gcloud, avro, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to ingest an Avro file (produced with Spark 3.0) into BigTable using the Dataflow template [1], and get below error.

N.B. This file can be read in Spark and Python `avro` library without apparent issue.

Any idea ?

Thanks for your support !

**Error (short)**

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found topLevelRecord, expecting com.google.cloud.teleport.bigtable.BigtableRow, missing required field key
```

**Avro schema (extract)**

`{"type":"record","name":"topLevelRecord","fields":[{"name":"a_a","type": ["string", "null"]}, ...]}`

**Error (full)**

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to start reading from source: gs://myfolder/myfile.avro range [0, 15197631)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$BoundedReaderIterator.start (WorkerCustomSources.java:610)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$SynchronizedReaderIterator.start (ReadOperation.java:361)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop (ReadOperation.java:194)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start (ReadOperation.java:159)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute (MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.executeWork (BatchDataflowWorker.java:417)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork (BatchDataflowWorker.java:386)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork (BatchDataflowWorker.java:311)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork (DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:140)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call (DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:120)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call (DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:107)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found topLevelRecord, expecting com.google.cloud.teleport.bigtable.BigtableRow, missing required field key
at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction (ResolvingDecoder.java:292)
at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance (Parser.java:88)
at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readFieldOrder (ResolvingDecoder.java:130)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord (GenericDatumReader.java:215)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion (GenericDatumReader.java:175)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read (GenericDatumReader.java:153)
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read (GenericDatumReader.java:145)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.AvroSource$AvroBlock.readNextRecord (AvroSource.java:644)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.BlockBasedSource$BlockBasedReader.readNextRecord (BlockBasedSource.java:210)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource$FileBasedReader.advanceImpl (FileBasedSource.java:484)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource$FileBasedReader.startImpl (FileBasedSource.java:479)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.OffsetBasedSource$OffsetBasedReader.start (OffsetBasedSource.java:249)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$BoundedReaderIterator.start (WorkerCustomSources.java:607)
```

References:

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#avrofiletocloudbigtable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigTable is a scalable NoSQL database service, which means is schema-free; whereas Spark SQL has a schema as you indicated on your question.

From the below error, it's referring you to BigTable [row key](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design#row-keys)

```
expecting com.google.cloud.teleport.bigtable.BigtableRow, missing required field key
```

Therefore, you would need to create your BigTable schema design by following this [process](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-steps).

Since HBase is also schema-free, your use case could be solved by using [Bigtable and the HBase API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/scala/bigtable-shc), if you're flexible to use **Spark 2.4.0**

As for the above use case, it looks to be a valid feature request, which I would file to the product team and update you with the report number.

Comment: Thanks @Ismail. So you suggest to either define a BigTable schema upfront that maps the Avro schema or to use the mentioned connector to write from Spark directly into BigTable ?

Comment: @py-r I would start with the connector

Comment: Thanks. Trying my chance, but facing [new issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65429730/spark-hbase-where-to-find-an-up-to-date-connector)